# convert link to slide transition when open in mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I am developing a website in which I want to convert as follow :

When we fill the starting details and start the test then the test is starts, what I want is :

when the site is opened in mobile then the `next button should be hide and slide transition should be used means when the user slides left to right then the next element should be shown`. How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use media-queries and Slick Slider or some other slider to create a slide transition.

Create slider and hide it with `display: none`, for exampple, and when browser width is < or = 500px (mobile width, check with media-query) hide the button and add `display: block` for slider.